# In yii2 gridview, i want to show value in place of foreign key ids

Tags: ajax, gridview, datagridview

Please tell me details process and files in which changes need to make for showing the foreign key value in place of id as shown in the snap below:

[Data Gridview generated using Ajax Crud Generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDymR.jpg)

My Scenario is I have two table 1) Screen and 2) SubScreen Table, The
Table Screen has  two fileds screenId and screenName
And Table SubScreen has subscreenId subscreenName and Screen_ScreenId (as a foreign key) in the view of SubScreen Table I want to show screenName (from Screen table) in place of Screen_ScreenId (of SubScreen Table View)

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found a solution to show foreign key value in place of foreign key id: I am posting this solution so that others who face the same issue can use this method to implement this in their code..

In the model class a relation function need to be created in my case:
my model class is Subscreen.php this has a relation function

```
public function getScreenScreen()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Screen::className(), ['screenId' => 'Screen_ScreenId']);
}
```

the above mentioned function was auto generated when generated the model using the gii module.
What extra i did here in the model is added one more function code is as shown below

```
public function getScreenName()
    {
              return $this->screenScreen->screenName;
    }
```

-------------------------Model changes ends up here-----------------------------

Now come to the _columns.php file of the view which was auto generated while generating the CRUD code using the Ajax Crud Generator extension..

...

```
[
    'class'=>'\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
    'attribute'=>'Screen_ScreenId',
    'value'=>function($model){return $model->getScreenName();},

],
```

...

the last line in above code 'value'=>function($model) {return $model->getScreenName();}, is added by me as a extra line to get the functionality up in the view...this made it possible for me to show the ScreenName in place of their Id in the view.
Hope this will help you to solve the same issue...